# Power Query - Find Most Recent Dates Grouped by Key ID

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to find the most recent dates grouped by PPID. So if someone has multiple sources of income all with the same date I want to see those and remove all of their old income. Hope that makes sense.

The columns monthly, %AMI and %Pvty do not matter but I need to keep them.

The image shows in green which I would expect to see and the red I would want to remove.

[image]

I tried playing around with removing duplicates but I can't see anyway to achieve this that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Group by PPID
- Select the rows in each subgroup for which the Date = Latest date

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1_2"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"PPID", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Source", type text}, 
        {"Monthly", Int64.Type}, {"%AMI", Int64.Type}, {"%PvtY", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by PPID, then select the latest DATE rows for each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PPID"}, {
        {"All", (t)=>Table.SelectRows(t, each [Date]=List.Max(t[Date])),
        type table[PPID=Int64.Type, Date=date, Source=text, Monthly=Int64.Type, 
                    #"%AMI"=Int64.Type, #"%PvtY"=Int64.Type]}
    }),

//Expand the subtables
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Date", "Source", "Monthly", "%AMI", "%PvtY"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

***Results from your data***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In PowerQuery, one way

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"MinDate",(x)=>
    let a=Table.SelectRows(Source, each[PPID]=x[PPID]) [Date]
    in List.Count(a)>1 and x[Date]=List.Min(a) ),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([MinDate] = false)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"MinDate"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"PPID"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=_,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(a, "Custom", each Table.RowCount(a)>1 and [Date]=List.Min(a[Date])),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Custom] = false)
in Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom","PPID"}), type table}}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform( #"Grouped Rows"[data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn( #"Grouped Rows", "data", List,List),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Data",{{"Date", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: I haven't tried yours yet. Are you saying either yours or Ron's doesn't work?

Comment: They would both work. Depends on what you are looking for. He for example is harcoding all the extra columns, I am not but that might not matter.  etc.